# how to Leverage browser caching in django

Tags: python, django, caching

I made a small site in Django but while checking the site performance with Google pagespeed I get the recommendation as Leverage browser caching but i cant find a way to achieve it in django

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For views, you use the [`cache_control` decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#controlling-cache-using-other-headers).

---

For static content, do this in your web server configuration. If you're using nginx, here's what you need to add to your Nginx site configuration:

```
location ~* \.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
  expires 168h;
  add_header Pragma public;
  add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
}
```

You might want to customize this a bit (e.g. match your `STATIC_PATH` instead of extensions, or use different expires headers).

Comment: how do I cache images

Comment: @Sar009 How are you serving them?

Comment: I have a html template and am calling images in that

Comment: @Sar009 That's not what I asked. I'm asking where the image file is coming from. Is that serve using Nginx? Apache? Using Django itself?

Comment: @Sar009 Don't you have nginx sitting in front of gunicorn to serve images? You shouldn't use gunicorn to serve static content.

Comment: i am really sorry i am using nginx

Comment: @Sar009 Updated my answer — have a look.

Comment: Can you add an answer for Apache?

Comment: @ThomasOrozco: this attaches a `304` with cached assets. But there's got to be a better way. For example, is there a way such that the browser doesn't request the static images at all, and just uses what it has in its cache?